# Loading Images in Nested folders for building CNN in R with tensorflow

Tags: r, image, deep-learning

I am trying to build a CNN with R using tensorflow.
I have following structure;
Main directory(Images Folder) has got three sub-directories/sub folders for;

1. Train
2. Test
3. Valid

Each of these folders(trains, test,valid) have many sub-folders. all of these sub-folders have images.

so overall structure for Train/Test/Valid folder is;

```
->MainFolder
  ->Train Folder 
     -> Folder 1 
       -?image 1
       ->image 2 
       & so on
     -> Folder 2

   ->Test Folder
```

Path would be something like
C:\Users\akhicoda\Documents\mainfolder\dogImages\test\001.Affenpinscher\image1.png

I want to load these images in data frames. What is the best way to do this for building CNN?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to load them into? What do you mean by load?

Comment: by load, I meant accessing these images for training purpose.